Split data frame by group based on the occurance of an id
I'm trying to find a solution in base R that can split a data.frame in groups, based on values in a column (group), that are also dependent by the occurrence of values in another column (id).
For example:
I have a data.frame
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20), 
                group = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                num = c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),
                value = c(sample(10:90, 16, replace = TRUE), rep(c(21,67,80,69), times=1, each=2)))

> df
   id group num value
1   1     A 0.1    59
2   2     A 0.1    72
3   3     A 0.1    82
4   4     A 0.1    17
5   5     A 0.2    39
6   6     A 0.2    46
7   7     A 0.2    39
8   8     A 0.2    56
9   9     B 0.1    31
10 10     B 0.1    46
11 11     B 0.1    63
12 12     B 0.1    15
13 13     C 0.1    51
14 14     C 0.1    68
15 15     C 0.1    48
16 16     C 0.1    28
17 17     A 0.1    21
18 17     B 0.1    21
19 18     A 0.1    67
20 18     B 0.1    67
21 19     A 0.1    80
22 19     B 0.1    80
23 20     A 0.1    69
24 20     B 0.1    69

and I'm trying to split the data.frame based on the following groups:
> df
$`A`
   id group num value
1   1     A 0.1    59
2   2     A 0.1    72
3   3     A 0.1    82
4   4     A 0.1    17
5   5     A 0.2    39
6   6     A 0.2    46
7   7     A 0.2    39
8   8     A 0.2    56

$`B`
   id group num value
9   9     B 0.1    31
10 10     B 0.1    46
11 11     B 0.1    63
12 12     B 0.1    15

$`C`
   id group num value
13 13     C 0.1    51
14 14     C 0.1    68
15 15     C 0.1    48
16 16     C 0.1    28

$`AB`
   id group num value
17 17     A 0.1    21
18 17     B 0.1    21
19 18     A 0.1    67
20 18     B 0.1    67
21 19     A 0.1    80
22 19     B 0.1    80
23 20     A 0.1    69
24 20     B 0.1    69

The last group is identified by pairs based on the column id. Meaning, if the id comes in pairs (17,18,19,20), the group is considered a separate group (AB) compared to the group (A and B) where the id dose not come in pairs (1:12).
How can this be accomplished with base R? Can this be done using the function split()?

You can first use ave to generate the groups you wanted, then split base on it.
To have the last group named as A + B, you'll need to collapse the ave results with paste with + (or obviously, sub the previous toString results). To have it being split at the end, the most convenient way I can think of is to use fct_inorder in the forcats package, otherwise, use the excellent codes shared by @Friede if you want to stay in base R.
split(df, forcats::fct_inorder(ave(df$group, df$id, FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = " + "))))

$A
  id group num value
1  1     A 0.1    78
2  2     A 0.1    66
3  3     A 0.1    18
4  4     A 0.1    81
5  5     A 0.2    35
6  6     A 0.2    16
7  7     A 0.2    51
8  8     A 0.2    18

$B
   id group num value
9   9     B 0.1    45
10 10     B 0.1    87
11 11     B 0.1    90
12 12     B 0.1    52

$C
   id group num value
13 13     C 0.1    85
14 14     C 0.1    24
15 15     C 0.1    41
16 16     C 0.1    16

$`A + B`
   id group num value
17 17     A 0.1    21
18 17     B 0.1    21
19 18     A 0.1    67
20 18     B 0.1    67
21 19     A 0.1    80
22 19     B 0.1    80
23 20     A 0.1    69
24 20     B 0.1    69


and with split2 = \(x, f, ...) { f = factor(f, levels = unique(f)); split(x, f, ...) } the order is preserved.

@benson23 Thanks! That worked. Just a follow-up question: how can I change the label of the groups that come in pairs, i.e. instead of A, B, would it be possible to label them as A + B? Perhaps with FUN = paste?

@Friede Would be great, if the order is preserved, but I'm not sure, if I follow your suggestion. I would need to create another function in order to preserve the order? Can this be achieved within split or around it, without having to create another function?

@SchlaWiener, I wouldn't have suggested it if your expected result hadn't been the shape it is in. Please explain what is wrong with creating and adding a function entirely written in base R to the file.

@Friede I like the idea of preserving the order, it's definitely something I would prefer having in the solution above. I'm just no sure, if I understand what the function is doing. Is x here df and f the ave part? There's nothing wrong with having another function. I was just curious, if there is a way of achieving this without adding a new function.

Look in the help file. help("split"). And, oviously, you could write split(x=df, f=factor(x=f<-ave(df$group, df$id, FUN=toString), unique(f))), but this is advanced.

Updated my answer :) @Friede thanks for the discussion!

Thanks to both of you @benson23 and @Friede! Your input helped a lot!

As long as user @benson23 does not protest, I would like to add what is suggested in the comments below this answer.
In base, without adding a custome function to the environment, preservence of factor ordering can be achieved as follows:
> split(df, factor(f <- ave(df$group, df$id, FUN = \(g) paste(g, collapse = "+")), unique(f)))
$A
  id group num value
1  1     A 0.1    54
2  2     A 0.1    81
3  3     A 0.1    40
4  4     A 0.1    15
5  5     A 0.2    35
6  6     A 0.2    22
7  7     A 0.2    83
8  8     A 0.2    69

$B
   id group num value
9   9     B 0.1    24
10 10     B 0.1    83
11 11     B 0.1    46
12 12     B 0.1    49

$C
   id group num value
13 13     C 0.1    63
14 14     C 0.1    46
15 15     C 0.1    32
16 16     C 0.1    45

$`A+B`
   id group num value
17 17     A 0.1    21
18 17     B 0.1    21
19 18     A 0.1    67
20 18     B 0.1    67
21 19     A 0.1    80
22 19     B 0.1    80
23 20     A 0.1    69
24 20     B 0.1    69


